# How to plotting binary matrix only 1(one) elements in R

Tags: r, plot, binary-matrix

I have a sparse matrix .csv file and save the Matrix like:

```
v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 ... vn
1 0  1  0  1  0  0
2 0  0  0  1  0  0
3 0  0  0  0  1  0
4 1  0  0  0  0  1
5 1  0  1  0  1  0
...
m
```

I want make plot's `x value = v1~vn , y value = 1~m`
and marking only non-zero elements(only 1)

in Matlab I use spy(), but I don't know how do this in R.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `SparseM` package:

`m <- matrix(as.numeric(runif(100) > 0.9), ncol = 10) # create random sparse matrix
library(SparseM)
image(as.matrix.csr(m)) # plot it :)`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using `ggplot2::ggplot`.

```
# Sample data
set.seed(2017);
df <- matrix(sample(c(0, 1), 100, replace = TRUE), nrow = 10);
df;

# Convert wide to long
library(reshape2);
df.long <- melt(df);

# Var1 = row
# Var2 = column
library(ggplot2);
gg <- ggplot(subset(df.long, value == 1), aes(x = Var2, y = Var1));
gg <- gg + geom_point(size = 2, fill = "blue", shape = 21);
gg <- gg + theme_bw();
gg <- gg + labs(y = "Row", x = "Column");
gg <- gg + scale_y_reverse();
```

[image]